# Display records from one part of the query first, followed by the records mathching the second part

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,pic0,bio,url FROM ".$table." WHERE id LIKE '%custom%' || ( category IN ('cat1') AND model = 'bmw'");`
```

And I am displaying them in a loop like:

```
while ($slice = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ }
```

Is there a way to firstly display the records from:  `WHERE id LIKE '%custom%'`

And after display the records from: `|| ( category IN ('cat1') AND model = 'bmw'");`

Ty for your answer.

Here is an updated sql code which I did to be sure the duplicates are removed automaticly:

```
(
SELECT 1 AS sort_col, performerid, pic0
FROM `cronjob_reloaded`
WHERE performerid IS NOT NULL
)
UNION (

SELECT 2 AS sort_col, performerid, pic0
FROM `cronjob_reloaded`
WHERE performerid IS NOT NULL
AND category
IN (
'Girl'
)
)
ORDER BY sort_col
```

And they are not. The first select gets the same result as the select nr two, but mysql shows me all the rows combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a union

```
$result = mysql_query("(SELECT 1 as sort_col,id,pic0,bio,url FROM ".$table." WHERE id LIKE '%custom%') UNION  (SELECT 2 as sort_col,id,pic0,bio,url FROM ".$table." WHERE  category IN ('cat1') AND model = 'bmw') order by sort_col";
```

edit: removed the warning about duplicates (according to mysql union docs, dupes are removed automatically),  added sort_col to make sure the order is kept.

Comment: Does union really guarantee that the order of results is kept?

Comment: Ty very much for your answer, this is great. One problem. Are you certain about duplicates? are they removed automaticly? I updated the question with a sql query test. Ty

Comment: according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html duplicates should be removed

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
SELECT id,pic0,bio,url 
FROM ".$table." 
WHERE id LIKE '%custom%' || ( category IN ('cat1') AND model = 'bmw'")
ORDER BY (id LIKE '%custom%') DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the results into two different variables based on a conditional, then output the variables in whatever order you like outside the loop. Because there may be things that might satisfy both parts of the query, the conditional would be what you think is really important to separate. So if it's crucial that the bmw results go last you could do something like:

```
//In Loop
$model = $slice['model'];
if($model != bmw){
$displayFirst.= $RecordsToDisplay;
}
else{
$displaySecond.= $RecordsToDisplay;
}
//End Loop
echo $displayFirst;
echo $displaySecond;
```